# Google Play Games Service - Get List of running matches

Tags: android, google-play-games

I'm working on a TurnBased Game with the Google Play Games Service.
Now I would like to list all Games you are involved in the DrawerMenu so you could enter the games very easy and also see what games you are in...

My Question is, how do I get these Games and also how do I get them so I can reenter them on a click?

Hope I could make my Problem clear :)
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it:

```
static final int[] statusesToLoad = new int[]{
            TurnBasedMatch.MATCH_TURN_STATUS_INVITED,
            TurnBasedMatch.MATCH_TURN_STATUS_MY_TURN,
            TurnBasedMatch.MATCH_TURN_STATUS_THEIR_TURN,
            TurnBasedMatch.MATCH_TURN_STATUS_COMPLETE};

PendingResult<TurnBasedMultiplayer.LoadMatchesResult> loadMathesResult = Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.loadMatchesByStatus(mGoogleApiClient, statusesToLoad);
loadMathesResult.setResultCallback(new loadMatchesCallback());
```

And then in the callback you can get data buffers for all the active games you are involved in and all the invitations you received:

```
    private class loadMatchesCallback implements ResultCallback<TurnBasedMultiplayer.LoadMatchesResult>{

        @Override
        public void onResult(TurnBasedMultiplayer.LoadMatchesResult loadMatchesResult) {
            LoadMatchesResponse response = loadMatchesResult.getMatches();
            TurnBasedMatchBuffer myTurnMatches = response.getMyTurnMatches();
            TurnBasedMatchBuffer theirTurnMatches = response.getTheirTurnMatches();
            TurnBasedMatchBuffer completedMatches = response.getCompletedMatches();
            InvitationBuffer invitations = response.getInvitations();
            }
        }
    }
```

You can use these buffers just as you use `ArrayList`, but you need to keep in mind that google wants you to `release()` them after you are done. If you won't you're gonna get a notification in your logs about a data leak.

Comment: thanks for a detailed answer. But where can we find the matchIDs in the variables so that I use them to Cancel all matches using  cancelmatch().

Answer (score 0):

You should use this method:

```
Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.getInboxIntent(GoogleApiClient apiClient);
```

According to the [documentation of the method](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/TurnBasedMultiplayer.html#getInboxIntent%28com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient%29), this method returns an `Intent` that can be used to start an activity that shows invitations and matches.

Hope this helps. Any other questions feel free to comment and I'll try to answer.

Answer (score 0):

in iOS it is like this:
this one gets all matches where you have been invited and are waiting for you to answer, you can then change the GPGTurnBasedUserMatchStatusInvited to another type with autocomplete.

```
GPGTurnBasedModel *turnModel = [GPGManager sharedInstance].applicationModel.turnBased;
    NSArray *invited = [turnModel matchesForUserMatchStatus:GPGTurnBasedUserMatchStatusInvited];
```

there is also a function to get ALL the matches but it includes the finished ones, maybe you don't want that.